# How to input a line break to an InputBox

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, line-breaks

I've written vba code to make an InputBox pop up to the user, and I am looking for a way for the user to input a line break into the Input Box.

I've tried googling and searching on stack overflow, but didn't come across anything that answered my question. A lot of the resources I found explained how to include a line break in the *prompt* of the input box, but not how the end-user might input a line break into the input box.

Apologies if this has been asked already somewhere else!

Comment: You can add one after the input is gathered, but you cannot allow the user to put one in an inputbox. You would have to create your own custom input box form and code it all manually (which really wouldnt be all that hard)

Comment: Hi @braX, thanks for your help! Are you saying that in the code, I would write something like `str = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter string:",Type:=2) & vbNewLine`?

Comment: no, I am saying that after they click OK on the input box, you can add line breaks then.

Comment: You could (for example) instruct the user to use a period for a line break, and then after they enter it, you could change all the periods to line breaks, but that's about as close as you are going to get unless you make your own custom user form.

Comment: Use `UserForm` to create your own input box with custom functionality

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004864/how-can-i-allow-for-the-entering-of-multiple-lines-of-input-into-a-vba-inputbox